# COMSOL: get list of eigenfrequencies

Tags: matlab, comsol

In COMSOL, is there a way to get it to export a txt file with all the eigenfrequencies found during an eigenfrequency analysis? I suppose that it could be done through the MATLAB interface or through the COMSOL GUI.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Questions about how to use a software are off-topic here, and should be asked at the corresponding support forum (in this case, the [Comsol support forum](http://www.comsol.com/support/)).

Answer (score 1):

Under results node, there are Export and Reports options.

Right click on Export will give you some options for exporting your data.